# cocos2d-x How to add Videoview and Cocos2dxGlsurfaceview in same screen?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, android-videoview

I am developing game in android using cocos2d-x. This is my requirements.

1. 30% of screen will covered by VideoView.
2. 70% of screen will covered by Cocos2dxGlsurfaceview.

*I have create this xml.*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frmGame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

*This is Cocos2dxActivity.java in which I edit init() method to add VideoView.*

```
package org.cocos2dx.lib;

import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper.Cocos2dxHelperListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public abstract class Cocos2dxActivity extends Activity implements Cocos2dxHelperListener {
    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================

    private static final String TAG = Cocos2dxActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;
    private Cocos2dxHandler mHandler;
    private static Context sContext = null;
    private FrameLayout frmGame;
    private VideoView videoPlayer;

    public static Context getContext() {
        return sContext;
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sContext = this;
        this.mHandler = new Cocos2dxHandler(this);

        this.init();

        Cocos2dxHelper.init(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void runOnGLThread(final Runnable pRunnable) {
        this.mGLSurfaceView.queueEvent(pRunnable);
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================
    public void init() {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_cocos2dx_video1, null);

        frmGame = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.frmGame);
        videoPlayer = (VideoView) v.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);


        // FrameLayout
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams framelayout_params =
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                       ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        framelayout.setLayoutParams(framelayout_params);

        // Cocos2dxEditText layout
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams edittext_layout_params =
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                       ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Cocos2dxEditText edittext = new Cocos2dxEditText(this);
        edittext.setLayoutParams(edittext_layout_params);

        // ...add to FrameLayout
        framelayout.addView(edittext);

        // Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView
        this.mGLSurfaceView = this.onCreateView();

        // ...add to FrameLayout
        framelayout.addView(this.mGLSurfaceView);

        // Switch to supported OpenGL (ARGB888) mode on emulator
        if (isAndroidEmulator())
           this.mGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8 , 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);

        this.mGLSurfaceView.setCocos2dxRenderer(new Cocos2dxRenderer());
        this.mGLSurfaceView.setCocos2dxEditText(edittext);

        // Set framelayout as the content view
        frmGame.addView(framelayout,framelayout_params);
        setContentView(frmGame);
    }

    public Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView onCreateView() {
        return new Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView(this);
    }

   private final static boolean isAndroidEmulator() {
      String model = Build.MODEL;
      Log.d(TAG, "model=" + model);
      String product = Build.PRODUCT;
      Log.d(TAG, "product=" + product);
      boolean isEmulator = false;
      if (product != null) {
         isEmulator = product.equals("sdk") || product.contains("_sdk") || product.contains("sdk_");
      }
      Log.d(TAG, "isEmulator=" + isEmulator);
      return isEmulator;
   }

    // ===========================================================
    // Inner and Anonymous Classes
    // ===========================================================
}
```

But when I tried to put VideoView with Cocos2dxGlsurfaceview App crashes in init() method.

Error : child has already a parent.you must call removeview() first.

Please help me out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_cocos2dx_video1, null);
```

This code is the key point.

From this [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29), we can know the returned `View` is the root view, that is to say, this `v` is the parent view of `frmGame`.

So, to solve your problem, you can replace

```
setContentView(frmGame);
```

with

```
setContentView(v);
```

Comment: thanks man for catching my silly mistake. This is called height of frustration.

Comment: @ pktangyue one more question I want to get height and width of my CCLayer and origin of CCLyear added to the scene any idea about this?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia you can look at [this wiki](http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Coordinate_System?project_id=cocos2d-x), I hope it's helpful.